# Create spaces between grid spans in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I create some space between grid spans in Twitter bootstrap? I am using margin or padding, but both of them push the last grid span to a new line and breaks the layout. Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jUQEc/1/

And, some markup:

```
<div class="container-narrow">

      <h4 class="title">Featured Companies</h4>

      <div class="row-fluid" id="posts">
        <div class="span6 post">
          <h4 class="title">Company Details</h4>
          <div class="box">
            test
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 post">
          <h4 class="title">Company News</h4>
          <div class="box">
            test<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>test
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 post">
          <h4 class="title">Company News</h4>
          <div class="box">
            test<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>testtest<br>test<br>test
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span4 post">
          <h4 class="title">Company News</h4>
          <div class="box">
            test<br>test<br>test
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

You need to add the `container-fluid` class to the container. This will keep the left/right margins in tact when you bring the screen in.

Add a `box-sizing:border-box` to the `.box` class to tell the browser to keep all padding and margins inside the width defined by the span classes.

Lastly, you have a header tag inside the container but not in a row/span. You will probably get more consistent rendering if you wrap it up.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8RVx6/